# What does Anderson sense about Judge Dredd in the movie?

Tags: dredd

In the beginning of the movie [Dredd](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1343727/) (3D), there was a scene where Dredd meets Anderson and she makes a demonstration of her psychic powers.

She is placed in an interogation room and she starts by detecting his presence and then she says she's sensing "fury, control and something else, almost..." but she never gets to finish her sentence.

What might have been that last part she sensed about Dredd? Considering the long run of the comics, I suspect it was a nod of some sort toward a "secret" / less known trait of personality that was revealed in one of the many arcs

Comment: I can feel anger. And control. But theres something else. Behind the control. Something almost...(childlike).

Comment: The word "almost" indicates something completely and totally unexpected

Comment: Remember Master Blaster?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

apparently it is his doubts about the judicial system. You can read all about it here: [link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9331/rookie-andersons-initial-evaluation-of-dredd)

Comment: Wouldn't say it was his doubt about the system, not at that point of the movie, at least. From the interview about the comic-book sequel to the movee: "[This Dredd] is younger, a little more enthusiastic about his job as the years have ground him down less. **He doesn't have any of the creeping doubts about the system that may have crept in.**" Source: http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=47971 I guess that's the canon, so whatever Anderson sensed behind the control.. it was probably something else.

Comment: Can you summarise for us? If that link goes dead, your answer becomes worthless

Answer (score 7):

She senses compassion underneath everything else, and like his compassion - if it exists, it shouldn't be mentioned. It was a nod to the people who read the comics and understand the character. What makes Judge Dredd an awesome Judge is that he actually does care about Mega-City one and the people that live there, but he's not the type to go work at a soup kitchen. He cares, like a good Judge (or a Cop) should. He even starts to question the system later on in his life which is because of his compassion but being a young Dredd in the 2012 film his compassion is there but not so apparent.

Comment: Makes perfect sense that he would keep compassion the most deeply hidden/protected in such a brutal world.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's something along the trait line because if you remember when Dredd was shot he asks the other judge to wait and the other judge enters a monologue and he is then shot by Anderson.. How could he have known Anderson was even free of her captors let alone on the way to his aid..

Comment: He saw her behind the other judge lining up her shot.

Comment: @Monty129 for about 20 seconds?

Comment: @Adsy Yeah that seems about the correct amount of time it would take for her to maneouvor around the room in order to not alert the other Judge to her presence until she had a clear kill shot lined up.

Answer (score 0):

She senses anger, behind the anger control, behind the control something else it's almost like ....... I don't know enough canon to fit some unknown thread in there. But from the sentence she doesn't finish I would guess one of the following; chaos (front runner for me), sadness, pleasure, madness (kinda like chaos). I'm just guessing here.

Comment: We prefer answers with evidence. Can you offer anything to back this up? Also, I've removed the off-topic rant.